# How to update cryptsetup till version 1.6.1?

Tags: software-installation, encryption, luks, truecrypt

Hello current version of cryptsetup is not capable working with truecrypt partitions.
Versions after 1.5.x are capable.(http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/Cryptsetup160)
So here is the latest version of cryptsetup: http://cryptsetup.googlecode.com/files/cryptsetup-1.6.1.tar.bz2
Is it possible to install on Ubuntu and how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**1.3 System specific warnings**

**Ubuntu as of 4/2011**: It seems the installer offers to create LUKS partitions in a way that several people mistook for an offer to activate their existing LUKS partition. The installer gives no or an inadequate warning and will destroy your old LUKS header, causing permanent data loss. See also the section on Backup and Data Recovery.

This issue has been [acknowledged by the Ubuntu dev team](http://launchpad.net/bugs/420080).

**Update 4/2013**: I am still unsure whether this has been fixed by now, best be careful. They also seem to have added even more LUKS killer functionality to the Ubuntu installer. I can only strongly recommended to not install Ubuntu on a system with existing LUKS containers without **complete backups**.

> **Update 11/2014**: There seem to be other problems withe [sic!] existing LUKS containers and Ubuntu as well, be extra careful when using LUKS on Ubuntu in any way, but exactly as the Ubuntu installer does.

<sup>([source](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions))</sup>